# Angular promise chain automation

Tags: angularjs

I have this situation where i would to hit API one by one, here is what i have come up with:

```
GridServices.getProjects(data[1].status_id, vm.myProject)
.then(function(data){
  vm.myData1 = data;
  vm.counter[1] = data.length;

  $scope.statusTypes[1].projects = vm.myData;
}).then(function(){
  GridServices.getProjects(data[2].status_id, vm.myProject)
    .then(function(data){
      vm.myData2 = data;
      vm.counter[2] = data.length;

      $scope.statusTypes[2].projects = vm.myData;
    })
}).then(function(){
  GridServices.getProjects(data[3].status_id, vm.myProject)
    .then(function(data){
      vm.myData3 = data;
      vm.counter[3] = data.length;

      $scope.statusTypes[3].projects = vm.myData;
    })
}).then(function(){
  GridServices.getProjects(data[4].status_id, vm.myProject)
    .then(function(data){
      vm.myData4 = data;
      vm.counter[4] = data.length;

      $scope.statusTypes[4].projects = vm.myData;
    })
}).then(function(){
  GridServices.getProjects(data[5].status_id, vm.myProject)
    .then(function(data){
      vm.myData5 = data;
      vm.counter[5] = data.length;

      $scope.statusTypes[5].projects = vm.myData;
    })
}).then(function(){
  GridServices.getProjects(data[8].status_id, vm.myProject)
    .then(function(data){
      vm.myData8 = data;
      vm.counter[8] = data.length;

      $scope.statusTypes[8].projects = vm.myData;
    })
}).catch(function(err, msg){
  console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Basically it hit the API one by one, but it's kinda manual, is there a way you can set it up in a loop so it auto chain query one by one, (**Promise all** is not what i am looking for here, because i need query to come in until one is finished)

Thanks for any ideas or suggestion, i am learning a better way to resolve this type of problem.

Cheers

Comment: All these promises are independent of each other, so why wouldn't `$q.all` fit?

Comment: Why do they need to run consecutively? Why not in parallel?

Comment: $q.all doing all the queries and call back as whole, i need call one finish then go for next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting up function to perform the data retrieval that conditionally calls the next iteration. For example

```
var getProjectIteration = function(i) {
    return GridServices.getProjects(data[i].status_id, vm.myProject).then(function(data) {
        vm['myData' + i] = data;
        vm.counter[i] = data.length;
        $scope.statusTypes[i].projects = vm.myData;

        if (i < 8) {
            return getProjectIteration(i++);
        }
    });
};

getProjectIteration(1).catch(function(err, msg) { ... });
```

Comment: this one is awesome! very smart :)

Comment: I am going to implement it, but i got the idea. Thank you sir